# Regular expression help - sum the numbers in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, string

Not sure if this is the best approach but I have some string which represents the orientation of some blocks. For example '3V6V' means a row of 3 vertical blocks, and a row of 6 vertical blocks. '3V6V6V' means row of 3, 6, 6 all vertical. '4H4H4H4H' would be 4 rows of 4 horizontal blocks. i.e. every 2 characters constitutes a row. Each item will either have just horizontals or just verticals, no mix and match. What I need to do here is add the total of the digits to determine the total number of blocks. How can I do that? I was thinking do some kind of string.split() and then if an array item is a number, add it to a running total. Is there a better approach to this? '4H4H4H4H' would be 16 and '3V6V6V' would be 15. Can someone point me in the right direction? There must be a fairly easy way to do this.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: This question reminds me of the classic adage: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`

Comment: ... which reminds **me** about the following quote: *'And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.'* `-- Tomalak`

Comment: "every 2 characters constitutes a row"

So rows can never have 10 or more blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sum = Regex.Split(input, "[HV]")
                .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                .Sum();
```

Note that this will accept malformed input like "3H3" or "3H6V"

EDIT: In fact you can simplify this with String.Split:

```
int sum = input.Split(new[] { 'H', 'V' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Sum(str => int.Parse(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp i would use (not tested) is:

```
((\d+)(?<type>[HV]))((\d+)\k<type>)*
```

Via \k you ensure that only Hs or Vs are in the string, but not mixed. The return value is probably an array, so that you easy can sum up the numbers.

Comment: I could not get this to work. Visual Studio barks about a bad compile constant. I went with Lee's solution and it works great. Thanks tho. ~ck